# SSH ChrootDirectory to a shareable folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, users

I'm working with the following structure. I have a group to company and users associated with this company. I did as following:

1. Create the group `company`;
2. Create the users and added this group to users;

Each user has your own home directory, incluing the `.ssh` folder with them public keys.

3. Create a folder `/shared/company`;
4. Set group ownership `chgrp -R company /shared/company`;
5. Set group permissions `chmod -R g+rw /shared/company`;
6. Set the `setid` `find /shared/company -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;`;

Then I updated each `.bashrc` user file including `umask 002`.

Now, everything is okay. Users can access the shared folder, create and read files with the right permissions. But, now, I want:

**Force user automatic enter in the shared folder by using SSH**. What I mean is: user will make a new connection with your private key in the SSH, then, when logged, user will be located at `/shared/company` not in `/home/<user>`.

When I add to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` the instruction below:

```
Match Group company
    ChrootDirectory /shared/company
```

The connection is reseted and user can't connect. How do I solve it?

**Edit #1**

User can connect after change the property and permissions of /shared/company `chown root:root /shared/company` and `chmod 755 /shared/company`. But when logged in, user receives the message `/bin/bash: No such file or directory` and disconnect.

Comment: Do you really want `chroot`? This will leave the user unable to leave the directory (or go back to their `$HOME`). Why not add `cd /shared/company` to the end of `.bashrc`?

Comment: I don't want this users have any access to system than allowed.